# why I cant set value for the div?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set value for the div ,I tried many ways but all of them didnt work.
I think the syntax is correct because I made alots of research

```
.flip3d2{width:100px;height:100px;margin:10px; float:left;}
.flip3d2  .front{
position:absolute;
-webkit-transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0degdeg);
transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
background:#fc0;width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:7px;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
backface-visibility:hidden;
transition:-webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition:transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip3d2  .back{
position:absolute;
-webkit-transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
transform: perspective (600px) rotateY(180deg);
background:#80bfff;width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:7px;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
backface-visibility:hidden;
transition:-webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
transition:transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip3d2:hover  .front
{
-webkit-transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.flip3d2:hover  .back
{
-webkit-transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
transform:perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
</style>

<script>


var list = document.getElementsByClassName("mainwindow");
var list2=list.getElementsByClassName("flip3d2");
list2.getElementsByClassName("front").value = "red";
    list2.getElementsByClassName("front").text = "red";
list2.getElementsByClassName("front").innerHTML = "red";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainwindow">
<div class="flip3d2">
<div class="back"> box 2 - back</div>
<div class="front"> box 2 - front</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Itried three ways to set values for the div but no one work.

Comment: you need to made more research because syntax is not correct - research what getElementsByClassName returns, then you'll see why you're doing it wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX I think this question should be closed. With some more research OP should have figured it out. This is just another question about getElementsByClassName...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does getElementsByClassName return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-does-getelementsbyclassname-return)

Comment: Is the CSS really necessary?

Comment: Well at least you all said exactly what I was thinking when I read the syntax lmao

Answer (score 1):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a HTMLcollection(It is an array like object which can contain more than 1 element) object, not a direct dom reference so it doesn't have properties like `innerHTML`.

If you are sure about there will be only 1 element, then you can access the dom reference using the index, else you can iterate over the collection and set the content.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("mainwindow")[0];
var list2 = list.getElementsByClassName("flip3d2")[0];
list2.getElementsByClassName("front")[0].innerHTML = "red";

//to loop
//var els = list2.getElementsByClassName("front");
//for(var i = 0; i <  els.length; i++){
//  els[i].innerHTML = 'something'
//}
```

```css
.flip3d2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.flip3d2 .front {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0degdeg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
  background: #fc0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3d2 .back {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
  transform: perspective (600px) rotateY(180deg);
  background: #80bfff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3d2:hover .front {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip3d2:hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainwindow">
  <div class="flip3d2">
    <div class="back">box 2 - back</div>
    <div class="front">box 2 - front</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution before but it did not work ,I THINK the code is correct   but I do not know where is the fault

Answer (score 0):

Till a class attribute do not required to be uniq, when you query element from it, you will get an array of elements, note the "s" in getElementsByClassName.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("front")[0].innerHTML = "red";
```

Comment: I tried this solution before but it did not work ,I THINK the code is correct   but I do not know where is the fault

Comment: If you try to execute from the navigator console (F12 to open developer tools / navigate to javascript console) 

What kinds of errors do you get ? One possible error, is that because your javascript code is define before your html code, you have to wait untill the dom is ready before executing it. document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){/* Your js code here */ document.getElementsByClassName("front")[0].innerHTML = "red"; });

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code. As Arun P Johny's answer mentioned, [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), an [array-like object](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/), not a DOM node. You'll notice the **s** in getElement**s**ByClassName, any DOM method that has Element**s** in it's name returns a `HTMLCollection`. Methods like `getElementById` (no **s**) return a single DOM node.

If you are used to using jQuery, jQuery provides an array-like object that has methods that will manipulate the whole collection, which might be why you are under the impression that you can do that with the collections that DOM methods return, but you unfortunately can't do that with `HTMLCollection`s.

Because `HTMLCollection`s are array-like, you can access their elements using bracket notation:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("mainwindow")[0];
var list2 = list.getElementsByClassName("flip3d2")[0];
list2.getElementsByClassName("front")[0].textContent = "red";
```

Or you could use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which will return a single DOM element based on a CSS selector:

```
var list = document.querySelector(".mainwindow");
var list2 = list.querySelector(".flip3d2");
list2.querySelector(".front").textContent = "red";
```

or if you don't need the reference to `.mainwindow` you could just do:

```
var list2 = document.querySelector(".mainwindow .flip3d2");
```

or if you don't need a reference to either `.mainwindow` or `.flip3d2` for other things you could just do:

```
document.querySelector(".mainwindow .flip3d2 .front").textContent = "red"
```

---

The other problem with your code is that the script tag is above the HTML markup for the elements you are trying to access. At the time you call `getElementsByClassName`, those elements don't exist so you get an empty `HTMLCollection` object. Move the `<script>` tag below the `<div>` tags to fix that. It is a good practice to put scripts as low in the page as possible, it helps avoid this [very common error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=move+script+tag+below+is%3Aanswer) and also [improves the performance of your page](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

---

A few other things,

- [HTMLDivElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement)s don't have a `.value` property, setting it does nothing meaningful (although it will create an [expando property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Expando).
- A div doesn't have a `.text` property, you are probably looking for [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- Using both `.textContent`  and `.innerHTML` is redundant. `.textContent` will set the text of the element and then `.innerHTML` will immediately overwrite it. Use `.textContent` if what you are setting is pure text without any mark up. If you are injecting HTML from a reliable source (not user provided, that opens you up to [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)) you can use `.innerHTML`.